# Swift passing array values when present model dismissing time

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

My scenario, I am having `tabbar` with three `viewcontroller` and first `tabbar` viewcontroller I am showing `tableview` with some `data`. Whenever I am clicking the `tableview` `cell` I am passing the data to one special present `model` popupcontroller. If I `dismiss` popup controller I need to show directly to tabbar `index 1` (I mean tabbar second `viewcontroller`) also need to pass the `values`.

Here, below code I tried

1. After select the tableview cell passing values to popupview controller
2. Popup close button click to pass the same value to tabbar index 1 (tabbar second viewcontroller)

Inside popup view controller

```
var item : Datum! //Datum Codable Root

@IBAction func close_click(_ sender: Any) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "disconnectPaxiSocket"), object: nil)
    if let presenter = presentingViewController as? HomeViewController {
           presenter.updatitem = item
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Once popup `dismissed` showing `tabbar` first `viewcontroller` (index 0), so I added `NotificationCenter` to call function and change the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you don't need to use `NotificationCenter` for that because you can simply achieve it by passing the `UITabBarController` object to next view controller when you select any cell in `tableView` like shown below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
    vc.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    vc.tabBar = self.tabBarController
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and you need to declare `var tabBar: UITabBarController?` into `DetailViewController` which will hold the value passed by previous view controller.

Then when you dismiss the view controller you can simply select the another index of `UITabBarController` with `self.tabBar?.selectedIndex = 1` and you can simply pass the value to first index view controller like:

```
@IBAction func close_click(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

        if let secondTab = self.tabBar?.viewControllers?[1] as? SecondViewController {
            secondTab.selectedIndexFromFirstTab = self.selectedIndex
            secondTab.tfData = self.userTF.text!
        }
        self.tabBar?.selectedIndex = 1
    })
}
```

and you need to declare objects in `SecondViewController` like:

```
var selectedIndexFromFirstTab = 0
var tfData = ""
```

Which will hold the data of previous view.

Now your result will look like:

[image]

For more info you can refer [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07312079188816625486) demo project.

**EDIT:**

So from your code I have seen that you have embed in navigation controllers to your `tabBar` controllers so you need to update `close_click` method like shown below:

```
@IBAction func close_click(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

        if let navView = self.tabBar?.viewControllers?[1] as? UINavigationController {
            if let secondTab = navView.viewControllers[0] as? HomeViewController {
                secondTab.selectedIndexFromFirstTab = self.selectedIndex
                secondTab.item = self.item
                secondTab.tfData = "Sample"
            }
        }
        self.tabBar?.selectedIndex = 1
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Dharmesh Kheni. I will check and update here

Comment: Is it possible to hide bottom tabbar bar once i reached second VC? @Dharmesh Kheni

Comment: Have you checked my demo project?

Comment: Sorry. Now i am checking. @Dharmesh Kheni

Comment: Sure thats fine. It will help you to understand the logic here.

Comment: Value not passing @IBAction func close_click(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            
            if let secondTab = self.tabBar?.viewControllers?[1] as? HomeViewController {
                secondTab.selectedIndexFromFirstTab = self.selectedIndex
                secondTab.tfData = "Sample"
            }
            self.tabBar?.selectedIndex = 1
        })
    } @  Dharmesh Kheni

Comment: are you sure HomeViewController is your second tab?

Comment: Yes. That is my second tabbar ViewController @Dharmesh Kheni

Answer (score 0):

You could use the completion handler of the dismiss method.

```
 dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Instead of passing nil, Pass a method to change the Tab bar to second tab.

The completion handler in the dismiss view controller, gets called when the dismissing of the view controller is completed.

```
viewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
            FunctionToChangeToSecondTab()
        })
```