# How can we pass the closures to any ViewController in the app flow?

Tags: ios, closures, swift4.2, pass-data

In View Controller A,

```
var completionBlock: (((String) -> ()))? = nil
```

& I am calling the completion block like(ViewController A):

```
if let block = completionBlock {
     block("block data to pass") 
}
```

I don't want to pass the completion data to ViewController B, instead i want to pass to ViewController C which is presenting from ViewController B.

In simple words, i want to pass the closure data to from ViewController A to ViewController C.I know how to pass data with delegates, just curious with closures?

How can we achieve that?

Comment: Nothing different? Just create another completionBlock in VC B and pass it to VC C

Comment: @Tj3n Is there no way to pass it directly like in delegates?

Comment: What do you meant by pass it directly? With delegate you also need to create a delegate var in VC B and pass it to VC C in order to trigger

Comment: @Tj3n I mean to pass the data directly from VC A to VC C lets say one string, i want to access in VC C from A. With delegates, it is possible to pass it from A to C. How can i achieve same in closures?

Comment: one ugly but straight forward way would be, View Controller C passes the closure to ViewController B, ViewController B can than pass the same closure to ViewController A, finally when ViewController executes the block, code executes in ViewController C n not in B :) Make sure you don't hold / pass strong reference in block else code will lead to leaks

Comment: But If I were in your place I would rather consider using unwind segue :) Read about it :) I know where this question is coming from, but there scenario was different and looking at OPs question I assumed OP us new to iOS development hence did not mention abut unwind segue, you look familiar with concepts of iOS use unwind segue rather than passing block or delegates :) Finally if you are writing Rx you can solve it much more elegantly

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari For your second last comment, i think it is kinda complex and not good approach to use closures that way.For sure,i will not hold the strong references to the closures, sometimes, when the value is vanishing we have to hold strong references also.

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari your right with RxSwift, i am still new to reactive programming, but sure will get it a shot some day.Interestingly, segue are easy to maintain, still the question is there how will unwrap the value in ViewController C if the segue is pushing from B to C, as it is not linked to A, how will you wind segue in that case?

Comment: @harjot-singh: I thought view controller C presented B and B in turn presented A isn't that the case? If yes than C is a super parent of A you can still have unwind segue then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188753/discussion-between-harjot-singh-and-sandeep-bhandari).

Answer (score 1):

If this block is something that you need to pass between several viewControllers, you have few options:

1- Pass closure as a variable: Create a variable on each new ViewController in the middle of VC-A, VC-C and pass them in between

for example:

```
//View Controller B:
var block:(((String) -> ()))? = nil

//Pass from A-B
if let viewcontrollerB = XXXX { //instantiate ViewController B from A
    viewcontrollerB.block = self.block
}


//ViewController C:
var block:(((String) -> ()))? = nil

//Pass from B-C
if let viewcontrollerC = XXXX { //instantiate ViewController C from B
    viewcontrollerC.block = self.block
}

//Call the block from ViewController C
if let block = self.block {
   block("block data to pass") 
}
```

2-Pass via Notification Center
You can pass this block from Any View Controller to Any Other:

```
//send notification:
let notification = Notification(name: Notification.Name("pass block"), object: block, userInfo: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
```

3-Access from shared object
Use a singleton design and create a static shared object and read/write to the object from different view controllers

```
//AppDelegate:
static var block:(((String) -> ()))? = nil

//ViewController A:
AppDelegate.block = XXX

//ViewController C:
if let block = AppDelegate.block {
   block("block data to pass") 
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering, still i know these approaches to pass data between VCs, 2nd and 3rd i know, but first approach to pass closures between three VCs, is there no any otherway to pass it directly to C?

Comment: If you initiate VC-B,VC-C inside VC-A, and handle the present logic inside VC-A you could pass directly from VC-A to VC-C.

Comment: Can you ellaborate with example, i am not getting what do you mean in code, please be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a sample code i quickly wrote for you, you can modify objects based on your need. Hopefully will address your problem.

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    var block:(((String) -> ()))? = { input in
        print(input)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "A"
        let VCB = ViewControllerB()
        let VCC = ViewControllerC()
        VCC.block = block
        VCB.VCC = VCC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VCB, animated: true)

    }


}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    var VCC:ViewControllerC?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .gray

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if let VCC = VCC {
            self.present(VCC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


}

class ViewControllerC: UIViewController {
    var block:(((String) -> ()))? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        //Will run the block that has been passed
        block?("test")
    }


}
```

Comment: i went through as you have said you wrote it quickly, still it doesn't answer my question as the block in your VC A is different and in VC C is different and plus the ViewController C reference in your VC A is different from the ViewController C itself, even if i try to pass the block, i won't be able to get data in VC C. Btw, thanks for your effort, i am still thinking how can i pass the data from A to C.